# How do i integrate Spring Actuator with AngularJS (state ui routers) and Springboot integration setup?

Tags: angularjs, spring, spring-boot-actuator

i see all spring actuator gets called like localhost:\Actuator..
I am having angular JS as front end where all states are written in JS file, so above URL does not receive any response by mere adding actuator dependencies. Please suggest.